# CSS hide drop down arrow in select tag on printing

Tags: css, html, printing

My HTML code goes here

```
<select> 
  <option value="mr"> Mr. </option>
  <option value="mrs"> Mrs. </option>
</select>
```

When i print the page i dont want to get the drop down arror, how to hide using css?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
border: none; /* If you want to remove the border as well */
background: none;
}
```

Apply the above css on print

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what browser you are using...

I haven't found a solution for Firefox yet but the rest should be done with:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
.noarrow{

   overflow: hidden;

}

.noarrow select {
  width: 100px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;    
}
```